# Autolayout UITextView inside UIScrollView size not correct

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout

So I know there are already a lot of questions about this subject, but I haven't found one that has solved my problem (or perhaps I don't understand the answer).

Alright, so I have set up a scrollview that has an UIView in it, containing an image view at the top (a gradient view which you can ignore), and a textview under it. The textview has to expand with whatever is put inside of it without scrolling (hence why it's in the scrollView).

I have in code:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    [self setupGradientView];
    [self resize];
}

- (void) resize {
    CGFloat maxWidth = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
    CGRect newFrame;

    // reset width for scrollview
    newFrame = imageView.frame;
    newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(maxWidth, imageView.frame.size.height);
    imageView.frame = newFrame;
    gradientView.frame = newFrame;
    newFrame = textView.frame;
    newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(maxWidth, textView.frame.size.height);
    //textView.frame = newFrame;


    newFrame = dummyView.frame;
    newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(maxWidth, dummyView.frame.size.height);
    dummyView.frame = newFrame;

    // resize height
    CGFloat fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width;
    CGSize newSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
    newFrame = textView.frame;
    newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, newSize.height);
    //textView.frame = newFrame; 
    self.textViewHeightConstraint.constant = newSize.height;

    CGFloat dummyViewHeight = textView.frame.origin.y + textView.frame.size.height;
    dummyView.frame = CGRectMake(dummyView.frame.origin.x, dummyView.frame.origin.y, dummyView.frame.size.width, dummyViewHeight);
    [scrollView setContentSize:dummyView.frame.size];

}
```

Unfortunately, the content size seems to be off by what I think may be 16pts, resulting in a view that looks like this with the text cut off (don't mind the unicode mess in the text):
[image]

Here's a picture of what the view looks like in IB: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGeZw.png

Here's what the constraint hierarchy looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMlw6.png

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:** If I comment out the entire code in the resize function, I get the same result. It would appear that auto-layout is resizing all of this after the function is called...but I thought auto-layout was completed when viewDidLayoutSubviews was called?

**Edit 2:** I have tried and found that adjusting the frame of the textView even n viewDidAppear has no effect. (I can edit things such as the background color)

Comment: You want the UITextView to grow down, instead of horizontally? Is it expanding Horizontally? I am not sure what you want exactly...

Comment: I want it to grow down, so I use sizeThatFits and set a static width (the width of the screen) and a CGFLOAT_MAX for the height.

I'm getting the calculations right, but for some reason it is not displaying correctly

Comment: Is your resize method being called? Try setting breakpoint.

Comment: Yes it is being called, and the values of the frames are correct

Comment: re: Autolayout, last I checked this, Autolayout updateConstraints is called after viewDidLayoutSubviews. You can check, just override -updateConstraints and/or other AutoLayout methods (and don't forget to call super)

Comment: Checked, updateConstraints is called before viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: Instead of setting the frame manually, set autolayout constraints to make the text view.leading and text view.trailing equal to the parent container (scrollview) and programmatically set the constant for your height constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up having to do was setting equal width and equal height to the view (not the scrollview), and then manually changing the height constraint in viewDidLayoutSubviews, along with changing the frame of the textView and the content size of the scrollView.